# routerLinkActive Does Not applies class

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am having a menu and having two elements in it. I want to apply a particular class based on the route using routerLinkActive. But the classes are not being applied. The error which i get is :

> Error: Uncaught : InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('demo_class demo_class--active') contains HTML space

My code in component.html

```
<nav class="class-bar">
    <ul class="class-bar__menu">
      <li class="class-bar__item">
        <a [routerLinkActive]="['demo_class demo_class--active']"  routerLink = "/xyz">Item1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="class-bar__item">
        <a [routerLinkActive]="['demo_class demo_class--active']" [routerLink] = "['/abc']">Item2</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: The error can't be clearer : remove the space from your string. If you want two classes, stop using the input syntax, or provide an array of two items.

Comment: i am new to angular and will like some example @trichetriche if possible. I also tried just using the child i.e. demo_class--active which did not work out.

Comment: Then you should start by providing a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: For that, you can use https://stackblitz.com, which is an easy to use Angular sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
 <li routerLinkActive="'demo_class demo_class--active'">
```

Comment: you must add it in LI

tag, I checked it befor sending

Comment: <li routerLinkActive="'demo_class demo_class--active'">
       <a  [routerLink]="'/live'">LIVE</a>
</li>

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your code as below:

```
<a routerLinkActive="demo_class"
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
   routerLink="/xyz">Item1</a>
```